# Get the cell background color in PhpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using Excel5 in my project. I have already tried the following codes:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->getARGB();
```

and

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFill()->getEndColor()->getARGB();
```

but these codes are returning wrong color. The `getStartColor()` always returning `FFFFFFFF` and `FF000000` for `getEndColor()` instead of red.

I don't know what am missing. Can any one help me in figuring this out?

Comment: Are you reading the file with setReadDataOnly(TRUE)? Otherwise, I've just done a simple test with solidfill red/yellow/green/blue and the above code returned FFFF0000, FF00B050, FFFFFF00 and FF0070C0 as I'd expect.

Comment: yes the setReadDataOnly() is set as true. I'm using Excel 2002 and I don't know if the getFill function is working properly with the version I'm using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

setReadDataOnly(TRUE) means read only the ***data*** from the cells, but none of the styling... and as background colours are part of the styling the reader will ignore background colours when it loads the file... if the fill style is not loaded, then the call to $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFill() will return default fill style and colours.

Load the file with setReadDataOnly(FALSE) and you should find it works

**EDIT**

This is way beyond the scope of PHPExcel.... everything is populated via DDE, including most of the styling, so the underlying fill colour is plain (as returned by the PHPExcel getFill colour call) until the external executable TOS.exe populates the data and sets the styles accordingly. Your only option here is to use COM so that the workbook is being executed in MS Excel itself.

Comment: Still not working, I have already tried to turn it false early. It only reverse the output of the getStartColor and getEndColor. I really need to fix it soon. :(

Comment: If it doesn't work, then can you please upload a sanitized example of the workbook and your code to the codeplex issues board - I tested it myself successfully less an hour or so ago, so clearly you've found a circumstance in which the fill style can't be read.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFill()->getEndColor()->getARGB();
```

Works , it just returns a color hex code (FF0000).

RGB = Red Blue Green = xx xx xx

FF0000 is actually RED.

Comment: But getEndColor is always returning FF0000 even in the other cells, which color are green.