# How do I remove column in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to remove highlighted column from my Excel sheet. Please check the code:

```
// generate report
if($genReport) {
    include_once("../../../includes/dbcon/mysql-crm.php");

    //01.generate first date and last day
    $month_end = date('d', strtotime($toDate));
    $month_first = date('d', strtotime($fromDate));

    include("../../../includes/addons/php-excel-gen/PHPExcel.php");
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Shanka Nuwan")
                         ->setLastModifiedBy("Shanka Nuwan")
                         ->setTitle("Call Center Report - ".$reportNamePart)
                         ->setSubject("Call Center Report - ".$reportNamePart)
                         ->setDescription("Call Center Report - ".$reportNamePart)
                         ->setKeywords("Call Center Report - ".$reportNamePart)
                         ->setCategory("Call Center");
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:C1');
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(15);

    $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
    $objPayable = $objRichText->createTextRun($reportNamePart);
    $objPayable->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPayable->getFont()->setSize(14); 
    $objPayable->getFont()->setColor( new PHPExcel_Style_Color( PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_DARKGREEN ) );
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue($objRichText);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A2', 'Date');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A3', 'SHOWROOM');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(10); 

        //add allboder style
        $BStyle = array(
            'borders' => array(
              'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
              )
            )
          );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:BI105')->applyFromArray($BStyle);

    $row = 4;

    // generate report column
    $column = 'B';
    $column2 = 'C';
    $x = $month_first;

    for(;$x<=$month_end;) {

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column2.'3', 'Enquiry');
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column2.'2', $x);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setVisible(false);

        $x++;

        if($x<=$month_end) {
            $column2++;
            $column = $column2;
            $column2++;
        }
    }

    // add total column after dates
    $column2++;
    $column = $column2;
    $column2++;
    //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($column.'2:'.$column2.'2');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A105', 'Total');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column2.'3', 'Enquiries Total');
    /*
    $styleArray = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
        'size'  => 15,
        'name'  => 'Verdana'
    ));
    */
    $styleArray = array('font'  => array('color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')));
    //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column.'2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column.'3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column2.'3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);


    //report name letter style
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(11); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:'.$column2.'2')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    $style = array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            )
        );
    //align report headers
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:'.$column2.'2')->applyFromArray($style);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:'.$column2.'3')->applyFromArray($style);

    //load location
    $get_sql ="SELECT
    showrooms.showroom_id,
    showrooms.showroom_code,
    showrooms.showroom_name,
    showrooms.showroom_address,
    showrooms.address_city,
    showrooms.manager_name,
    showrooms.manager_mobile,
    showrooms.manager_id,
    showrooms.shop_email,
    showrooms.shop_phone,
    showrooms.shop_fax,
    showrooms.showroom_type,
    showrooms.added_date,
    showrooms.last_update,
    showrooms.added_by,
    showrooms.status_id
    FROM
    showrooms
    INNER JOIN showroom_type ON showrooms.showroom_type = showroom_type.showroom_type_id
    WHERE showrooms.showroom_id > '0' and  
    showrooms.showroom_type = '1' AND 
    showrooms.status_id = '1'
    ORDER BY
    showrooms.showroom_name ASC";

    $get_showroom = $db->get_results($get_sql);
    if($db->num_rows>0){
        $row = 4;
        foreach($get_showroom as $row_showroom){    
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$row , $row_showroom->showroom_name);
            //get showroom id
            $showroom_email= explode('@',$row_showroom->shop_email);
            $showroom_id = $showroom_email[0];
            //check showroom already intract with showroom task
            $sso_user = $db->get_row("SELECT users.user_id FROM users WHERE users.login_name = '".$showroom_id."'");
            $total_inqury = 0;
            if($db->num_rows == 1){
                $user_id =  $sso_user->user_id;
                //date check
                $column = 'B';
                $column2 = 'C';
                $day = $month_first;
                for(;$day<=$month_end;){
                    $byear = date('Y',strtotime($fromDate));
                    $month = date('m',strtotime($fromDate));

                    $check_date = strtotime($byear.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
                    $user_login = $db->get_row("SELECT 
                                                    Count(sys_id) AS locount 
                                                    FROM 
                                                        sys_user_login 
                                                    WHERE 
                                                        user_id = '".$user_id."' 
                                                    AND log_date = '".date('Y-m-d',$check_date)."'");//$db->debug();
                    if($db->num_rows == 1){
                        if($user_login->locount > 0){
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column.$row , '');
                            $styleArray = array('font'  => array('color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')));
                            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column.$row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                            //$total_login++;

                            //back groud color for cell
                            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column2.$row)->applyFromArray(
                                                                    array(
                                                                        'fill' => array(
                                                                            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                                                                            'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFF00')
                                                                        )
                                                                    )
                                                                );
                        }else{
                            //$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column.$row , '');
                        }
                    }else{
                        //$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column.$row , '');
                    }

                    //count inquery
                    $inquery_day = $dbCrm->get_row("SELECT
                                                    Count(customers.cu_id) AS inq_day 
                                                    FROM
                                                    customers
                                                    WHERE
                                                    customers.added_by = '".$user_id."' AND
                                                    customers.added_date LIKE '".date('Y-m-d',$check_date)."%'");//$db->debug();
                    if($dbCrm->num_rows == 1){
                        if($inquery_day->inq_day > 0){
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column2.$row ,$inquery_day->inq_day);
                            $total_inqury += $inquery_day->inq_day;
                        }else{
                            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column2.$row , '0');
                        }
                    }else{
                        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column2.$row , '0');
                    }

                    $day++;
                    if($day<=$month_end){
                        $column2++;
                        $column = $column2;
                        $column2++;
                    }
                }
                $column2++;
                $column = $column2;
                $column2++;

                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($column2.$row, $total_inqury);                               
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                                            ->setCellValue(
                                                'C105',
                                                '=SUM(A10:E9)'
                                            );
                $styleArray = array('font'  => array('color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')));
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column2.$row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                $total_inqury = 0;
            }
            $row++;
        }
    }


    //genarate report data
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="showroom-task-report-'.$byear.'-'.strtolower(date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10))).'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
?>
```

below excel out will generate from the above coding. I tried lot of hours to figure out how to get ride of it. Still can't find the solution.

[image: excel file]

Comment: please go through this link. It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113520/get-the-cell-background-color-in-phpexcel?answertab=votes#tab-top.   I t will help you to find the color of field. So that you can check whether it is highlighted.

Comment: do you mean by yellow color in my excel sheet ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the Worksheet object's `removeColumn()` or `removeColumnByIndex()` methods.

`removeColumn()` accepts a column id by name (e.g. `D`, `F`, `L`).

`removeColumnByIndex()` accepts a column id by its index number (e.g. 3, 6, 12)

Comment: can you give me the details in advanced ? I'm new to this stuff

Comment: What more details do you need? `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeColumn('F');` will remove column `F` in the current active wrksheet.... column `G` will then become column `F`, column `H` will become column `G`, etc

Comment: Okay, but i have 60 columns to remove

Comment: So you have to call `removeColumn()` 60 times, once for each column (unless you have consecutive columns, because it will accept a second argument of the number of columns to remove)

Comment: can you see the image ? I've already highlighted things want me to delete. code doesn't work. where should i put this code ?

Comment: Yes, I can see the image..... you put it wherever it feels appropriate in your code: I'd probably put it at the end, just before you save the file.... and I'd probably work backwards from the last column to remove to the first, because that's more efficient

Comment: Though theh alternative would be to rewrite your code so that it wasn't leaving those blank columns in the first place